# Starting a .cmd file from the desktop with a shortcut key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cmd.exe

I am working on an .cmd file that is saved on the local disc (C:) and created a shortcut to it on the same location. I also set the shortcut to run on the key combination "ctrl+Lshift+1" from the desktop menu. For some reason it doesn't work so I would be glad if anyone could help. Respectfully, 2dumb4name.

Comment: Windows update has  broken link keyboard shortcuts unless the link is in a specific folder. You could use a third-party tool such as Clavier+ to make a functional shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just try  notepad and paste "C:\yourfilename.cmd" and save it as a .bat file then make shortcut to the bat file.